# OpenCV: How to calculate essential matrix from feature matches between two images from different cameras using 5-point algorithm?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Basically I want do to the same thing as this function here:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga13f7e34de8fa516a686a56af1196247f

However, the parameter description states, that this algorithm assumes that the matched feature points of the two images are from cameras with the same camera matrix.

What if I have matched features, but images from two different cameras with different camera matrices? How can I calculate the 5-Point essential matrix then?

**Additional question**: 
If I have calculated the essential matrix can I just use it as parameter in the method [`computeCorrespondEpilines()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga19e3401c94c44b47c229be6e51d158b7) instead of the fundamental matrix, assuming images are already rectified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenCV there is no standard function for calculating the essential matrix using two different cameras. But it is very easy to implement it yourself.
You can add a function to the `five-point.cpp` and recompile OpenCV.
I just added an overloaded function `cv::findEssentialMat` with an additional parameter for the second camera matrix.

```
cv::Mat cv::findEssentialMat(InputArray _points1, InputArray _points2, InputArray _cameraMatrix1, InputArray _cameraMatrix2, int method, double prob, double threshold, OutputArray _mask)
{
    CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION();

    Mat points1, points2, cameraMatrix1, cameraMatrix2;
    _points1.getMat().convertTo(points1, CV_64F);
    _points2.getMat().convertTo(points2, CV_64F);
    _cameraMatrix1.getMat().convertTo(cameraMatrix1, CV_64F);
    _cameraMatrix2.getMat().convertTo(cameraMatrix2, CV_64F);

    int npoints = points1.checkVector(2);
    CV_Assert(npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints &&
        points1.type() == points2.type());

    CV_Assert(cameraMatrix1.rows == 3 && cameraMatrix1.cols == 3 && cameraMatrix1.channels() == 1);
    CV_Assert(cameraMatrix2.rows == 3 && cameraMatrix2.cols == 3 && cameraMatrix2.channels() == 1);

    if (points1.channels() > 1)
    {
        points1 = points1.reshape(1, npoints);
        points2 = points2.reshape(1, npoints);
    }

    double fx1 = cameraMatrix1.at<double>(0, 0);
    double fy1 = cameraMatrix1.at<double>(1, 1);
    double cx1 = cameraMatrix1.at<double>(0, 2);
    double cy1 = cameraMatrix1.at<double>(1, 2);
    double fx2 = cameraMatrix2.at<double>(0, 0);
    double fy2 = cameraMatrix2.at<double>(1, 1);
    double cx2 = cameraMatrix2.at<double>(0, 2);
    double cy2 = cameraMatrix2.at<double>(1, 2);

    points1.col(0) = (points1.col(0) - cx1) / fx1;
    points2.col(0) = (points2.col(0) - cx2) / fx2;
    points1.col(1) = (points1.col(1) - cy1) / fy1;
    points2.col(1) = (points2.col(1) - cy2) / fy2;

    // Reshape data to fit opencv ransac function
    points1 = points1.reshape(2, npoints);
    points2 = points2.reshape(2, npoints);

    threshold /= (fx1 + fy1) / 2;

    Mat E;
    if (method == RANSAC)
        createRANSACPointSetRegistrator(makePtr<EMEstimatorCallback>(), 5, threshold, prob)->run(points1, points2, E, _mask);
    else
        createLMeDSPointSetRegistrator(makePtr<EMEstimatorCallback>(), 5, prob)->run(points1, points2, E, _mask);

    return E;
}
```

Then you have to add the function declaration to `calib3d.hpp`, recompile and reinstall your OpenCV version.

> **Additional question:** If I have calculated the essential matrix can I just use it as parameter in the method `computeCorrespondEpilines()` instead of the fundamental matrix, assuming images are already rectified?

Yes, I think this should work.