# Change opencv source code hough.cpp with openmp and recompile opencv source code

Tags: opencv, compilation, openmp, houghlinesp

I wish to  make OpenMP changes in hough.cpp HoughLinesP/HoughLines function and recompile opencv source code to test the changes. How can I do this? I want to see performance improvements with openmp

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question here: [OpenCV: How to calculate essential matrix from feature matches between two images from different cameras using 5-point algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259668/opencv-how-to-calculate-essential-matrix-from-feature-matches-between-two-image/56270345#56270345)
I assume you are using Windows. You have to open your opencv library folder e.g.:
downloads → opencv-4.0.0 → modules → imgproc → src → hough.cpp

Now you can change something in your .cpp file (e.g. add a function or change function arguments). Remember to modify the according header file (found in imgproc → include) after your changes.

After this go into your build directory, start the OpenCV.sln, run ALL_BUILD and INSTALL and only the changed files are modified in your build directory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am using Ubuntu. Do I need to perform cmake , make  and make install again?

Comment: only make and make install

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer as correct if it helped solving your problem.